# Custom Authorization using ClaimsAuthorizationManager

Tags: c#

> How can i change the raw token value coming from acs with ClaimsAuthenticationManager.I want to add role to the token.i managed to add the role in the claimsidentity but it is not reflected in the raw token.

```
 string rawToken = string.Empty;

ClaimsIdentity identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

if (null != identity)
 {
   SimpleWebToken token = identity.BootstrapToken as SimpleWebToken;

    if (null != token)
     {
       rawToken = token.RawToken;
     }
  }
```

> Role is reflected at identity but its not getting added at bootstrap token.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap token is used to construct ClaimIdentity. In ClaimsAuthenticationManager you already have incomingPrincipal created from ACS token. Also claims inside token are signed by ACS and in theory cannot be changed without validation problem on token consumer.

What scenario you are trying to implement? Reusing token in WCF service or similar?

**UPDATE**
Here is a sample code to change token from ACS (with SAML2 token). 
NB: **It is very important that SAML assertions with different data have different IDs**. If implementing a scheme whereby an assertion "template" is loaded and certain bits of data are filled in, the Id must be changed, otherwise in debugger you will see modified assertion values but WriteToken method will write original unmodified token from source bytes stored inside token.

```
X509Certificate2 singingCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, certificatePassword);
Saml2SecurityTokenHandler handler = CreateTokenHandler();
Saml2SecurityToken baseToken = GetTemplateToken();
Saml2Assertion assertion = templateToken.Assertion;

//modify template token - change date, add claims etc
assertion.Id = new Saml2Id();
//order is important, because in sampleToken this property is already setup and NotBefore date can not be NotOnOrAfter
assertion.Conditions.NotOnOrAfter = DateTime.MaxValue;
assertion.Conditions.NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow;

//prepare to resign token assertions
X509AsymmetricSecurityKey signingKey = new X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(singingCertificate);
X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause x509clause = new X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(singingCertificate);
SecurityKeyIdentifier keyIdentifier = new SecurityKeyIdentifier(new SecurityKeyIdentifierClause[] { x509clause });
assertion.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials
    (
    signingKey,
    assertion.SigningCredentials.SignatureAlgorithm,
    assertion.SigningCredentials.DigestAlgorithm,
    keyIdentifier
    );
//create and sign modified token
Saml2SecurityToken token = new Saml2SecurityToken(assertion, new ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey>(new List<SecurityKey>() { signingKey }), templateToken.IssuerToken);
```

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/ASPNET-Security-SWT-With-a0183e7a/view/SourceCode#content

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/ASPNET-Security-SWT-With-a0183e7a/view/SourceCode#content(this is what i am tryin to implement).i did the authentication part with same approach as there in msdn link.now i am trying to authorize the user in rest scenario at the server side.for this i used claimsauthenticationmanager to modify the claims.i am able to add role to the claims value but its not reflecting to the token coming from acs.only i managed to add the role at claimsidentity.

Comment: If you really want to change a token you have to resign it with a private key of ACS certificate after changing. Or you can disable token validation on service side, but this will be mean that token is used just as a standard container to claims.

Comment: i am working on rest scenario.if i will disable token validation at service side then service will be exposed.Can't i change the token coming from acs?

Comment: You can you this code to change token:
`SimpleWebToken token = identity.BootstrapToken as SimpleWebToken;
token.AddClaims(ClaimTypes.Role, "MyRole")
identity.BootstrapContext = new BootstrapContext(token, handler);`
But digest of token now will be invalid and token validation will fail.
In my solution i use shared ClaimsAuthenticationManager, send unchanged token to a service and assign roles to Identity inside service again. 
Pro: short token (i have many roles), token validation, standard solution. 
Contra: two calls for roles (caching is required)

Comment: If you have a little set of roles you can use Rule Transformation on ACS side, this will add Roles Claims to token from ACS.

Comment: Thanks danila..but i don't think its a good practice still we have to search for better approach..

Comment: ya..i went through that one by adding rule group to generate roles but its not suitable for the scenario for many roles.

Comment: I'm using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2013/01/09/using-the-jwt-handler-for-implementing-poor-man-s-delegation-actas.aspx) guide, you may read more about ActAs with CreateChannelActingAs, CreateChannelWithIssuedTokens, and first i recommend to read Wrapup section. 
Vittorio Bertocci is a main evangelint of WIF.

Comment: I am confused between some scenarios. 1.how the ACT AS scenario works n how i can implement this one for adding role claims.  2.Can i use custom STS to refer some database. 3.when user is logging through IP's we r getting saml or swt at the web app side.can we post this token to acs n use WS-Federation identity provider to issue claims with additional claims.